# Views skip contextual filter IF current user is Administrator

Tags: views, 9

I have a View that has a contextual filter that uses a token to get entity reference values on the current user to limit a view (that also points at the same reference type). If they match up, that is all the View will return in its results.

However, for Administrator roles, I do not want to apply the filter (bypass it) without duplicating the view and having different views to maintain. I tried adding the first argument of "Authored by" using the current user, and checking the role of that user in the validation. This appeared to work at first, but when a node is authored by a lower level user, the validation appears to not work (no result shows). If I change the author to another user, the node appears in the View results for that lower level user.

Without having to duplicate a View, how can I grant Administrators full access but apply the second contextual filter otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a similar question I saw, I had to add this:

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  try {
    $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
    // If user is not admin, remove the authored by argument
    if ($view->id() === 'portal' && $view->current_display == 'page_2' && !in_array('administrator', $account->getRoles())) {
      unset($query->where[0]["conditions"][0]);
      $query->where[0]["conditions"] = array_values($query->where[0]["conditions"]);
    }
  }
  catch(Error $e) {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addError('The server encountered a problem. Please contact the site\'s administrator.');
    \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->error("Error displaying Rate Manager: %e",
      ['%e' => $e]
    );
    return;
  }
}
```

This seems to support both cases, but now there is a code and argument position dependency that is not obvious from the UI. I wonder if there is a better solution?